# to_char returning wrong date postgresql

Tags: postgresql, formatting, to-char

So in my database i have a table with startimestamp that is "Timestamp with time zone" type
but what i want to display the timestamp without the time zone so i thought this would work

```
Select to_char("StartTimestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS')from "Samples" where "ID" = 20
```

and a i get

```
"2013/08/02 14:08:04"
```

but the when i do it without the to_char and just call the timestamp for the same id like this

```
select "StartTimestamp" from "Samples" where "ID"=20
```

i get this which is the correct one

```
"2013-08-02 14:31:04-07"
```

I'm i missing something the to_char statement? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `MM` to `MI` in the minutes place

```
select
    to_char(now(),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS'),
    to_char(now(),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
       to_char       |       to_char       
---------------------+---------------------
 2013/08/21 15:08:00 | 2013/08/21 15:51:00
```